# index out of range error when trying to get content of first item in query

Tags: python, django

I have a query set:

```
messages = Message.objects.all()
```

I want to get the 'content' on the first item regardless.

I have tried this:

```
  messages[1].content
```

but this gives me an index out of range error.

Comment: *first item* - `...[1]` - Spot your mistake yet? Python, as with most programming languages, is 0-indexed. The item with index 1 is the *second* item.

Comment: O I see! indexes start from 0 in python silly mistake thanks .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
messages[0].content
```

Indexes are [0-based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering) in Python - meaning: the first element in a list is at index 0, the second at index 1, and so on. Another possible cause for the error would be that `Message.objects.all()` is returning an empty list.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your using Django 1.6 you can do

```
message = Message.objects.all().first()
```

and if you're using Django less than 1.6

```
message = Message.objects.all()[0]
```

what this will produce is basically a SQL LIMIT query.

```
SELECT * FROM Messages LIMIT 1;
```

You should definately read [this documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets) - It's about how Django handles slicing and pickling of QuerySets.

Answer (score 1):

the first is 0 not 1 try

```
messages[0].content
```